# How can I complete the picture below？

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to fill color in the close area like following.

[image]

I drew arcs which generates several closed area.  I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Here is my code. I tried to test it but failed. Or is there any other way to accomplish it?

Only the path code for the line.
Add path without line fill color before path code。

Xaml:

```
 <Canvas>
        <Path Fill="Yellow">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="210,165">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="60,40"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="155,20">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="55,180"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path  Fill="Blue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="80,200">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="120,10"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Green">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="20,95">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="200,30"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path  Fill="Green">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="30,130">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="225,110"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Stroke="DarkBlue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="210,165">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="60,40"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Stroke="DarkBlue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="155,20">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="55,180"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Path Stroke="DarkBlue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="80,200">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="120,10"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Path Stroke="DarkBlue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="20,95">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="200,30"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Path Stroke="DarkBlue">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="30,130">
                        <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="225,110"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
     
    </Canvas>
```

The result:

[image]

[image]

What should I do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Or complete each closed loop through the path, fill it with color, and then add path lines on the graph?